# How to deal with users that resubmit rejected edit suggestions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, edit-ban

I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7467539), which was the same edit as the user suggested [three hours earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7465240), but was unanimously rejected.

Other than voting to reject the new edit (since I do agree with the original decision), is there anything else that should be done to handle cases like this?

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to do anything more, though one might, depending on the case, use a more elaborate custom rejection reason.
If the user persists, he will be blocked for a short while soon, which will make him look at the review sometime soon.

That is btw. the way I found out about it myself, once upon a time. My only ban yet.

Comment: It takes a *lot* of rejected edits to actually get edit banned.  Dozens.  And with the incorrect-approval rate being as high as it is, it's *extraordinary* hard to actually get enough rejections to get banned, outside of the trolls and spammers.  Spending 3-4 edits before the same one finally gets approved isn't going to get you a ban as long as you only do that a few times each week.

Comment: Well, it was when I was getting started, maybe the criteria were  bit more stringent then. Or I made too many borderline / inapproprite edits then anyway. Who knows. (I hope they were not bad though, only overreaching.) Also, that was in the times when not substantial enough edits could be rejected.

Comment: Anyway, do you have a better idea?

Comment: @Servy - Thankfully, we'll be able to do something about the worst offenders soon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits#comment821383_221832