# User who resubmits rejected drafts

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-proposals, proposed-changes

I've been watching the Proposed Changes in the [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topics) tag and at least one user keeps submitting poor changes.

I then explain why they aren't good changes and reject the draft. On more than one occasion I've come back the next day to find they've resubmitted the same draft which was then accepted by 3 less experienced users with questionable proposals of their own.

What, if anything, should be done in a case like this?

Comment: Related: [How to deal with users that resubmit rejected edit suggestions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288702/2415822).  I would mod flag, writing up an answer now.

Comment: Throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330300/my-topic-was-rejected-then-it-was-copied-with-the-same-code-and-my-image-and-ap

Comment: Just ignore Documentation entirely until it is either fixed or removed from SO.

Comment: Stop the negativity already on docs - they have already proposed doc updates almost weekly - they have meta to file bugs, they have chat if you have questions.  Yes it is a little rough but jeez o peas give it a rest already.

Comment: "What should I do when another user does X bad thing?" An enormously large portion of the time, the answer to any question of this form is, "Flag for attention." I'm really not sure why this isn't people's go-to solution when they see stuff that's clearly bad. Questions about, "Is this bad?" and, "I flagged, this happened. Now what?" I can understand, but if it's egregious and you haven't flagged already... I don't know why people post questions about it.

Comment: @JonH Sometimes negativity is a healthy attitude. Not everything people try is good, and it's better to be realistic about it than to ignore the problems. That said, "ignore the entire feature" doesn't seem like a good idea, of course; how would you even know it *has* problems if people do that? But "negativity" isn't really a good description of the problem with that attitude. I wish people would be stop being so negative about a little negativity. =p

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you feel that a user continuously submits bad suggestions/drafts I would flag for moderator attention, explaining the situation and linking to the accepted and rejected proposals.  A moderator will evaluate and may implement a suggestion ban on the user for suggesting too many poor edits.

Additionally, you can reach out to a moderator in chat as outlined in [What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) if you feel that raising a flag on one of the user's random posts is inefficient, or if the user has no posts on main.

Comment: How would I put out a flag in this case? I don't see a way of flagging a particular user nor any of their drafts/edits.

Comment: You can raise a flag on any one of the user's posts on Stack Overflow, or flag the topic itself for moderator attention.  The key information here are the links to the reviews and user you will provide in the flag.

Comment: Flagging an unrelated post by the same user seems like an unnecessarily roundabout and prone-to-error way of raising this sort of concern. :/

Comment: @NathanielFord I'm open to other suggestions then.  Actually, the Stack Exchange theme recommends this method: "please flag **any post by the user in question** and leave a custom reason explaining what you think should be investigated." http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306266/2415822

Comment: Huhn; I had never seen that recommendation before. I should clarify that I'm not sure there is a 'better' way (other than a new feature allowing people to 'flag' a user - which has other impact), and I think your second suggestion seems on-point, I was just surprised at the 'flag any post by the user' suggestion. Thanks for the link!

Comment: It's even on the official [What if I see someone doing something bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging).  I'll edit my answer to add another option: reaching out to a mod in chat.

Comment: @JAL: Holy crap. Who are you!? The Flash? You responded to my message and fixed the typo in less time than it took me to write this message.

Comment: @Zaz: 53 seconds. Not _that_ fast....